# How to get n number of max salary in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have found following solution on google search, but I am not able to understand it. can anyone explain how this query processed.

```
SELECT *
FROM   employee_test e1
WHERE  3 = (SELECT DISTINCT count(*)
            FROM   employee_test e2
            WHERE  e2.emp_sal > e1.emp_sal)
```

Comment: That is a very inefficient way of doing it.

Comment: That query makes very little sense when trying to read it so it would be a nightmare to maintain....if it does infact work!! Can you share a sample of the table?

Comment: Also, do you want the "n" number of salaries to be a parameter of the stored procedure?  Or will it be fixed in the SQL e.g. always the top 10?

Comment: insert into Employee_test values('Anees',1000);
insert into Employee_test values('Rick',1200);
insert into Employee_test values('John',1100);
insert into Employee_test values('Stephen',1300);
insert into Employee_test values('Maria',1400);

Answer (score 2):

It's a very inefficient correlated query to return the employee with the 4th highest salary.

```
SELECT *
FROM   employee_test e1
WHERE  3 = (SELECT DISTINCT count(*)
            FROM   employee_test e2
            WHERE  e2.emp_sal > e1.emp_sal);
```

Assuming salaries (emp_sal) are unique, the subquery counts how many employees have a higher salary than the employee in 'e1'.  If the count is 3, then this is the employee with the 4th highest salary.

If there is a tie for 4th (e.g. through 6th or 10th), all the ties will be shown in the result.
If there is a tie that involves the 4th and one higher slot, e.g. 2nd to 4th or 3rd and 4th, then there will be no results, since NO value of emp_sal has EXACTLY 3 records with higher emp_sal values.

The better form would be

```
select top(1) with ties * 
from (
    select *, rn=rank() over (order by emp_sal desc)
    from employee_test
    ) x
where rn <= 4
order by rn desc;
```

This shows the outright 4th highest salary (and ties if any), or if there is a tie across persons 3rd through 6th (covering spot #4), it will show 3rd through 6th.

Comment: Thank u Sir for giving me answer, But i want more detail like is it done recursively or loop.......

Comment: There is no recursion involved. There is no TSQL looping code involved. Internally, the SQL Server engine is performing nested loops for the subquery, firing it once for EACH record in the outer query.